# Continue writing on GestureOverlayView untill user clear it

Tags: android, uigesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition

I am using a `GestureOverlayView` for drawing. I want gesture should remain as it is until I clear it. The problem is when I go for the next word the previous gesture get cleared. Here is my code:

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
    android:id="@+id/signaturePad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:fadeEnabled="false"
    android:gestureColor="@color/black"
    android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
    android:gestureStrokeWidth="1.5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

Where's my mistake?

Comment: why would GestureOverlayView keep the old gesture on its surface?

Comment: I want to create sample for drawing diagrams. So i thought that i can go with GestureOverlayView. If i am wrong then what should i go for?

Comment: a custom drawing View,  this is a way you should  follow

Comment: ok thanks :) Then whats the difference between using custom drawing and GestureOverlayView